# `TypeError: 'DataFrame' object is not callable` trying to make bar graph

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, typeerror

**TypeError: 'DataFrame' object is not callable**

```
data2('New_deaths', 'New_cases').head().plot.bar(title= "Statistics of 
New_deaths and New_cases by country")#bar graph
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```py
data2['New_deaths', 'New_cases'].head().plot.bar(title= "Statistics of New_deaths and New_cases by country")#bar graph
```

This way, you’re not trying to call the data frame but you’re accessing it.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear. So, I'm giving answer on basis of what I think you wanted to do.
To plot one column of dataframe, the code will be like this:

```
data2["New_deaths"].head().plot.bar(title= "Statistics of New_deaths and New_cases by country")
```

Or

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
x = data2["New_deaths"].drop_duplicates()
graph = ax.bar(x, data = data2["New_deaths"].head(), height= data2["New_deaths"].max() + 100, label="data")
ax.set_title("Statistics of New_deaths and New_cases by country")
plt.show()
```

If you are trying to plot two columns of your dataframe at a time like side by side bars, you can checkout this: https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/barchart.html#sphx-glr-gallery-lines-bars-and-markers-barchart-py

If you are trying to do groupby:

```
data2.groupby(["New_deaths","New_cases"]).head().plot.bar(title= "Statistics of New_deaths and New_cases by country")
```

The link for pandas groupby: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html